# New line is added to result when splitting long sed expression to multiple lines

Tags: sed

What is the right way to split sed expression? when I'm trying to split the expression to two lines I'm getting a new line in the result.

example:

```
sed -e '/server.w123.path/s/"\/usr\/lib\/u1\/"/ \
 "\/var\/tmp\/"/g' <  t1.test
```

I'll get the results in two lines

```
server.w123.path , 
/var/tmp
```

instead of one line(in case the sed expression is in one line:

```
 server.w123.path, /var/tmp
```

Comment: `\\` is part of the replacing string,

Answer (score 1):

You can not split a `s` command this way (you are not in your shell here but in a sed command).

Doing this, your `\` is considered as a char (a newline one) added before the replacement string. In other words, you replace your pattern with `\n\/var\/tmp\/`